# Angular Firebase - html video downloaded 2 times

Tags: angular, firebase, html5-video, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am using Angular 9 Universal for SSR. My application is hosted on Firebase Hosting and for SSR I am using firebase functions.

**Problem:**
On home page, I have HTML  as a background (displaying it only when platform is browser). When I access the website locally using **firebase serve** command, the video is downloaded only 1x. However when I access website hosted on firebase hosting, the video is downloaded 2x. This causes my hosting downloads to be really high.

**Screenshots (see size difference)**

Firebase hosting:
[image: Network on firebase hosting]

Firebase serve:
[image: Network on firebase serve]

**Code:**

```
<video *ngIf="isBrowser" autoplay playsinline loop muted oncanplay="this.play()" (canplay)="onVideoLoaded()" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true">
<source src="../../../../assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What's the difference between your 2 screenshots?

Comment: Size of the videos. And complete MBs transferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is the reason of this behaviour, but I was able to solve this issue by moving the video to firebase storage and using the video url instead of path to assets video.